# Forge 1.7.10 : Error while "gradlew setupDecompWorkspace"

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I was trying to setup my modding environement and when i did 'gradlew setupDecompWorkSpace', this happen :

```
WARNING: You are using an unsupported version of ForgeGradle.
Please consider upgrading to ForgeGradle 4 and helping in the efforts to get old versions working on the modern toolchain.
See https://gist.github.com/TheCurle/fe7ad3ede188cbdd15c235cc75d52d4a for more info on contributing.
#################################################
         ForgeGradle 1.2.2-g2ea0336
  https://github.com/MinecraftForge/ForgeGradle
#################################################
               Powered by MCP unknown
             http://modcoderpack.com
         by: Searge, ProfMobius, Fesh0r,
         R4wk, ZeuX, IngisKahn, bspkrs
#################################################
:extractMcpData UP-TO-DATE
:getVersionJson
Unexpected reponse 403 from http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.7.10/1.7.10.json
:extractUserDev UP-TO-DATE
:genSrgs SKIPPED
:extractNatives UP-TO-DATE
:getAssetsIndex
Unexpected reponse 403 from https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/indexes/1.7.10.json
:getAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':getAssets'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.862 secs

C:\Users\Dimitri\eclipse-workspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src>
```

I've tried to change the gradle version into the gradle-wrapper.properties from 2.0 to 2.6, It just lasted longer.

Comment: The error is quite clear. It could not fetch the required JSON due to error 403 (forbidden). You are unlikely to find support for 1.7.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a professional in this but my workaround when I had this problem was replacing forge gradle with anatawa12's fork. I think what happened was some urls changed in one of the forge updates and forge 1.7.10 wasn't considered in the change.

New gradle: https://github.com/anatawa12/ForgeGradle-1.2

**How to fix the Problem Method 1:**

1. Follow: https://github.com/anatawa12/ForgeGradle-example#how-to-replace-forgegradle-12-with-anatawa12s-fork
2. Edit Gradle wrapper to use gradle 4.4.1 or higher.

**How to fix the Problem Method 2:**
Download and use anatawa12's example gradle template (same commands for cmd):
https://github.com/anatawa12/ForgeGradle-example/archive/master.zip